# Set onclicklistener add text instead of replacing it?

Tags: android, textview, onclick

So I have 4 buttons, each button gives a letter. I eventually want this to unlock a password.

But how do I get the letters to be added after each other instead of replacing the previous one?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt;
Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton2);
    btn3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton3);
    btn4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton4);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txt.setText("t");

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txt.setText("i");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply get the text from before and add the new String to it.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        txt.setText(txt.getText() + "your String here");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a simple way :)

Comment: @Astorian you should accept this answer as the correct one.